# Running a terminal command from NSButton click

Tags: macos, cocoa, terminal, nsbutton

I'm trying to build a basic Mac OS Application using Xcode which allows the user to force eject a CD that gets stuck in their drive without having to reboot their computer each time. Basically I want to have an `NSButton` on my window labeled "Eject" and I'm looking for the button to execute the Terminal command "drutil tray eject" to forcefully eject the CD from the drive when not responding. I'm kinda a newbie to Xcode and this is my first Mac App.

Thank you! :-)

Answer (score 0):

Use `NSTask`. Have a look at [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTask_Class/Reference/Reference.html) and [Quartz Composer CommandLineTool](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/samplecode/CommandLineTool/Listings/CommandLineToolPlugIn_m.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40009314-CommandLineToolPlugIn_m-DontLinkElementID_4).

```
+ (void) executeShellCommandAsynchronously:(NSString*)command
{
    NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
    NSTask *task = [[[NSTask alloc] init] autorelease];
    [task setLaunchPath: @"/bin/sh"]; //we are launching sh, it is wha will process command for us
    [task setStandardInput:[NSFileHandle fileHandleWithNullDevice]]; //stdin is directed to /dev/null
    NSArray *args = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:  @"-c", //-c tells sh to execute commands from the next argument
                     command, //sh will read and execute the commands in this string.
                     nil];
    [task setArguments: args];
    [task launch];
    [command release];
    [pool release];
    return;
}
```